# convert short url to long url using powershell or c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have got some short URLs which come from `http://tinyurl.com/` and I need to convert them to long URLs. One example of that is: `tinyurl.com/zclueny`.

Can someone show me how can I retrieve the long url either using powershell or c#?

I found this api: untiny.me/api/1.0 but it seems that it is not available anymore and is marked as malware.

Comment: Just perform an HTTP request to the short URL, and grab the Location header from the response. See duplicate.

Comment: I was just using that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How can I close this question post, since it is a duplicate?